# Why ASCII T-SQL function return a number when use non english characters?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ascii, non-ascii-characters

I know that `ASCII` (without extensions) does not understand non English characters, but why when I put this:

```
SELECT ASCII('Ñ')
```

The function returns 209. Is it using an extension, or what it happens? Thanks for the answer in advance.

Comment: A great number of uses of the term "ASCII" are just wrong. While one might be reluctant to rename functions or introduce new ones, at least the documentation should be updated! Too often, ASCII is to character code as Kleenex is to facial tissue. It would be on this list of [genericized trademarks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_generic_and_genericized_trademarks) if it was a trademark.

Answer (score 1):

**209** number is **ACP code value** for `Ñ` *Latin Capital Letter N With Tilde* valid for any of `ACP1250`, `ACP1252`, `ACP1254`, `ACP1257` and `ACP1258` [encodings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964658.aspx#e) (see supplement below).

Read MSDN reference (applies to: SQL Server, starting with 2008):

> [ASCII (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177545.aspx) Returns the **ASCII code value** of the
>   leftmost character of a character expression.

This is slightly succinct but is it concise and *precise* as well? I don't think so: originally based on the English alphabet, ASCII encodes **128** specified characters into ***seven-bit*** integers as shown by [the ASCII chart](http://www.techonthenet.com/ascii/chart.php). However, **209** number returned from `ASCII('Ñ')` is an ***eight-bit*** integer, apparently.

**In fact**, the `ASCII` function returns the **ACP code value** of the leftmost character of a character expression (see [**ACP**: Acronym for the Windows (`ANSI`) code page in use](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964658.aspx#a).)
For proof, let's put to use next effect: [the `ASCII` function is the opposite of the `CHAR` function](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/functions/ascii.php) in SQL Server (Transact-SQL). The MSDN reference says a bit more about it:

> [CHAR (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187323.aspx) Converts an int **ASCII code** to a character.
>
> Syntax
>
> ```
> CHAR ( integer_expression )
> ```
>
> Arguments
>
> `integer_expression` Is an **integer from 0 through 255**. NULL is
>   returned if the integer expression is not in this range.

BTW, all this discrepancy comes from notorious terminology confusion, i.e. generously misusing (interchanging) terms like `ASCII`, `ANSI`, `CP` or even terms like `UNICODE`, `UTF-16`, `UCS-2` etc. etc.

**Supplement**: Windows ANSI character table for code **209** (the table below comes from my small `.bat` script):

```
ACP     Hex  codepoint  #Description
---     ---  ---------  ------------ 
CP1250  0xD1    0x0143  #LATIN CAPITAL LETTER N WITH ACUTE
CP1251  0xD1    0x0421  #CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER ES
CP1252  0xD1    0x00D1  #LATIN CAPITAL LETTER N WITH TILDE
CP1253  0xD1    0x03A1  #GREEK CAPITAL LETTER RHO
CP1254  0xD1    0x00D1  #LATIN CAPITAL LETTER N WITH TILDE
CP1255  0xD1    0x05C1  #HEBREW POINT SHIN DOT
CP1256  0xD1    0x0631  #ARABIC LETTER REH
CP1257  0xD1    0x0143  #LATIN CAPITAL LETTER N WITH ACUTE
CP1258  0xD1    0x00D1  #LATIN CAPITAL LETTER N WITH TILDE
```